# Fill in gaps in geom_area chart

Tags: r

When I produce a `geom_area` graph using the below code there are white gaps between the groups.
Can anyone suggest a way to fill them in? I initially thought it was due to there not being zeros for each group in the code, when I add them, it just has a diagonal line from the top of the chart to the bottom. This is a common solution to the answers on SO but doesnt work in this example.

```
library(tidyverse)
date<-as.Date(c('2022-05-02','2022-05-09', '2022-05-16', '2022-05-23', '2022-05-30','2022-06-06'))
total<-c(1,1,1,1,1,1)
gp<-c( "group1","group1", "group2","group2","group3","group3")
data<-data.frame(date,total,gp, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

data%>%  
  ggplot()+
  geom_area(aes(x=date, y=total, fill=gp, group=gp))
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand which white gaps you are talking about or what exactly you expect the desired result to look like. Can you make a sketch of the desired result?

Comment: I want a chart that is joined up so group 1 is touching group 2 and group 2 is touching group 3.

Comment: But you have dates on the x axis and the dates of the groups don’t seem to touch each other. So what should the x axis represent?

Comment: when i make the dates touch each other, the y axis then jumps to 2. the x axis represents dates but I want the groups to touch each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
data%>%  
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = total, fill = gp, group = gp))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 7) +
  scale_x_date(breaks = '1 week', expand = c(0.01, 0.01))
```

Output:

[image]